# Select rows from one table, using values from another table when present

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, union

I've got a "parameters" table like this:

```
id | job_id | value
1  | 100    | value1
2  | 100    | value2
3  | 100    | value3
4  | 200    | value4
5  | 200    |  
6  | 200    | value7
```

Then, for parameters that have list values, I've got a second, list_param_items table:

```
id | param_id | value
1  | 5        | value5
2  | 5        | value6
```

I'm trying to figure out a query that would allow me to get id, job_id, and value columns, containing data from the parameters table, except when a row in the parameters table has rows in the list_param_items table with its id, concatenate those to form its value column.

So if I were to select all parameters, I'd want to get this:

```
id | job_id | value
1  | 100    | value1
2  | 100    | value2
3  | 100    | value3
4  | 200    | value4
5  | 200    | value5,value6
6  | 200    | value7
```

I also need to be able to select all params for a given job ID and get the same data, just for that job. So, for job_id = 200:

```
id | job_id | value
4  | 200    | value4
5  | 200    | value5,value6
6  | 200    | value7
```

I've accomplished it with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT parameters.id, parameters.job_id, GROUP_CONCAT(list_param_items.value) AS value
FROM jobdetail_input
INNER JOIN list_param_items 
ON list_param_items.param_id = parameters.id
WHERE parameters.job_id = 200
UNION
SELECT parameters.* FROM parameters 
WHERE parameters.job_id = 200
) unmerged
GROUP BY id;
```

The problem with this is that, in reality, there are many more columns in the parameter table than I've shown here. So I'd prefer a way to do it without having to list out all the column names. The reason I had to list them all out was to eliminate the "value" column from parameters in the first SELECT statement, so that both sides of the UNION would have the same set of columns to work with. I'd like to not list them out so the query wouldn't have to be updated anytime a column is added.

The other question I have about how efficient that query is. Even if I have to list all the parameters table columns out, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Join the first table to a subquery of the second table which aggregates the values into a CSV string:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.job_id,
    COALESCE(p.value, lpi.value) AS value
FROM parameters p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT param_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value) value
    FROM list_param_items
    GROUP BY param_id
) lpi
    ON p.id = lpi.param_id
ORDER BY
    p.id;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo